# Is there a cut-less way to implement same_length/3?

Tags: prolog, logical-purity, non-termination

Say I want to assert that three lists are of the same length. I could do something like this:

```
same_length(First, Second, Third) :-
  same_length(First, Second),
  same_length(Second, Third).
```

This does the right thing when either `First` or `Second` are instantiated. It also works when all three arguments are instantiated! However, a call like `length(Third, 3), same_length(First, Second, Third)` causes it to return the correct answer (all three lists have length 3) with a choicepoint, then loop forever generating solutions which will never match.

I've written a version which I believe does the right thing in every situation:

```
same_length(First, Second, Third) :-
  /* naively calling same_length(First, Second), same_length(Second, Third) doesn't work,
     because it will fail to terminate in the case where both First and Second are
     uninstantiated.
     by always giving the first same_length/2 clause a real list we prevent it from
     generating infinite solutions */
  ( is_list(First), same_length(First, Second), same_length(First, Third), !
  ; is_list(Second), same_length(Second, First), same_length(Second, Third), !
  ; is_list(Third), same_length(Third, First), same_length(Third, Second), !
    % if none of our arguments are instantiated then it's appropriate to not terminate:
  ; same_length(First, Second), same_length(Second, Third) ).
```

I keep hearing about how the cut should be avoided when at all possible, is it possible to avoid it here?

As a bonus question, I think these are green cuts, since the final predicate is fully relational, is this true?

Comment: "Green cuts" are used to improve the efficiency of a program - they simply cut out computation that cannot possibly lead to a solution. "Red cuts" are used to eliminate unwanted solutions. They also improve efficiency, but they also change the possible output of a program. In other words, "green cuts" do not change the program's meaning, but "red cuts" are an integral part of the program producing the desired result.

Comment: I used to worry a lot about situations like this and produced similar-looking predicates with a lot of `var/1` and `ground/1` (which is essentially what you're doing here with `is_list/1`). Invariably, @false would show up and point out a dozen new ways my frankenstein predicate failed to behave in strange situations (lists with instatiated heads and uninstantiated tails, backwards-correctness, etc.) Now I just do the simple thing and hope that debugging it will be easier if I stumble into a strange instantiation pattern in practice.

Comment: By the way, I really enjoy your questions, please continue to ask them!

Comment: Terminologyproblem: You are using the word uninstantiated when you mean instantiated!

Comment: `same_length([_|_], _, []).` loops.

Comment: @DanielLyons: Please note that such "strange situations" happen typically, when an explanation is generated for (say) failure. You then search for some maximum, like a maximal generalization such that certain properties still hold. If your definitions break in that respect you are just put onto a wrong trail.

Comment: @false, " You are using the word uninstantiated when you mean instantiated! " I've double-checked my post and I don't see where I'm using "uninstantiated" wrongly, where am I messing up?

Comment: @false, `same_length([_|_], _, []).`, hehe, just as Daniel predicted. You're very right! How did you come up with this, what was your intuition that helped you find this?

Comment: @DanielLyons thanks for the encouragement, hopefully my questions will slowly become more interesting ;)

Comment: @num1: Example: *This does the right thing when either First or Second are uninstantiated.* Counterexample: `same_length(_,[_|_],[]).` does not fail but loops.

Comment: @num1: You already accepted an answer, so I assume that is what you wanted as answer. I rather would write `maplist(\_^_^_^true, Xs, Ys, Zs)` in stead.

Comment: @false if you post that comment as an answer I'll certainly upvote it, I didn't 
 think there might be an even shorter answer.

Comment: @num1 it should've been https://lpaste.net/4663831766123937792. then `same_length([_|_], _, []).` terminates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not define `same_length/3` in the same way `same_length/2` is usually defined?

```
same_length([], [], []).
same_length([_| T1], [_| T2], [_| T3]) :-
    same_length(T1, T2, T3).
```

Works nicely when called with all arguments unbound:

```
?- same_length(L1, L2, L3).
L1 = L2, L2 = L3, L3 = [] ;
L1 = [_990],
L2 = [_996],
L3 = [_1002] ;
L1 = [_990, _1008],
L2 = [_996, _1014],
L3 = [_1002, _1020] ;
L1 = [_990, _1008, _1026],
L2 = [_996, _1014, _1032],
L3 = [_1002, _1020, _1038] ;
...
```

No spurious choice-point or non-terminating backtracking in the case you mention:

```
?- length(L3, 3), same_length(L1, L2, L3).
L3 = [_1420, _1426, _1432],
L1 = [_1438, _1450, _1462],
L2 = [_1444, _1456, _1468].
```

Comment: I'm fighting a strong urge to curse here because, wow, how could I have missed such a simple solution. Yeah, this is clearly the right way, thank you.